# How to find most recent full and incremental files using script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

We're using Veeam Agent for Windows for several machines which typically produces folders with contents like this:

```
2021-01-16  11:14 PM    69,181,009,920 DEV82021-01-16T230042.vbk
2021-01-17  11:02 PM     2,516,852,736 DEV82021-01-17T230037.vib
2021-01-18  11:03 PM     4,966,821,888 DEV82021-01-18T230106.vib
2021-01-19  11:02 PM     4,096,479,232 DEV82021-01-19T230103.vib
2021-01-20  11:02 PM     4,885,250,048 DEV82021-01-20T230103.vib
2021-01-21  11:02 PM     4,519,645,184 DEV82021-01-21T230037.vib
2021-01-22  11:02 PM     5,085,712,384 DEV82021-01-22T230037.vib
2021-01-23  11:17 PM    70,159,249,408 DEV82021-01-23T230038.vbk
2021-01-24  11:02 PM     3,897,864,192 DEV82021-01-24T230026.vib
2021-01-25  11:02 PM     6,467,932,160 DEV82021-01-25T230027.vib
2021-01-26  11:02 PM     5,735,276,544 DEV82021-01-26T230031.vib
2021-01-28  07:42 AM     6,019,416,064 DEV82021-01-28T074032.vib
```

What I need is to be able to capture the most recent .vbk file (full backup) and all of its related *.vib files (incremental backups). The script would run daily so if the most recent .vbk hasn't changed from previous run then skip uploading it and its related .vib files, uploading only new .vib files until a new .vbk is created. After 7 days a new .vbk would be created so we should be uploading this and any related .vib files.

Using example above the following files should be uploaded (we use gsutil):

```
2021-01-23  11:17 PM    70,159,249,408 DEV82021-01-23T230038.vbk
2021-01-24  11:02 PM     3,897,864,192 DEV82021-01-24T230026.vib
2021-01-25  11:02 PM     6,467,932,160 DEV82021-01-25T230027.vib
2021-01-26  11:02 PM     5,735,276,544 DEV82021-01-26T230031.vib
2021-01-28  07:42 AM     6,019,416,064 DEV82021-01-28T074032.vib
```

When the script runs again the next day, check if there's a new or changed .vbk or .vib file and upload them using gsutil. After 7 days, delete all old  .vbk files and its related .vib files leaving only the newest .vbk file and its newest related .vib files.

How can I capture these filenames into some variable using preferably a windows batch script or alternatively a powershell script, then process each file from the variable and upload it using gsutil with something like:

gsutil cp -n -r "\192.168.2.251\Backups%COMPUTERNAME%" gs://%Bucket%/"%COMPUTERNAME%"

Right now I have something like this:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('dir "\\192.168.2.251\Backups\%COMPUTERNAME%" /b /o-d') do (set newestvbk=%%i)
```

but this only gives me the newest .vbk (DEV82021-01-23T230038.vbk). I also need its related .vib files:

> DEV82021-01-24T230026.vib
> DEV82021-01-25T230027.vib
> DEV82021-01-26T230031.vib
> DEV82021-01-28T074032.vib

How do I capture the most recent vbk file AND all .vib files created afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir "\\192.168.2.251\Backups\%COMPUTERNAME%" /b /a-d /o-d') do (
 if /i "%%~xi"==".vib" echo backup %%i
 if /i "%%~xi"==".vbk" echo backup %%i&goto done
)
:done
```

Backing up each `vib` file until a `vbk` is found

[revision in response to comment - delete older .vib, .vbk]

```
set "keepme=Y"
for /f %%i in ('dir "\\192.168.2.251\Backups\%COMPUTERNAME%" /b /a-d /o-d') do (
 if /i "%%~xi"==".vib" if defined keepme (echo backup %%i) else (echo del %%i)
 if /i "%%~xi"==".vbk" if defined keepme (echo backup %%i&set "keepme=") else (echo del %%i)
)
```

Using `if defined` to interpret a batch switch named `keepme`. Before the loop, `keepme` is defined (the actual value is irrelevant). the `.vib` and `.vbk` files are processed as before, but after the first `.vbk` is backed up, `keepme` is set to *nothing* which makes it undefined, so further files of the selected extensions are deleted.

Comment: Let me know if I should create a new post for this but based on the above, which is working very well btw (thank you again!), I also need to delete all the remaining old .vib and .vbk files. So using your code, those are the files I will be keeping, but any other older .vib and .vbk files should be deleted. I'm not sure how I could do that and was hoping you could help. It can be another for loop as I'll put that in a separate function and then call it. I'm changed it to /B /A-D /OD but so far I'm only seeing the other older vbk that would be deleted but no .vib files are being deleted.

Comment: Can't seem to figure out how to add a code block here. Tried indenting a line with 4 spaces but no luck Anyway, so criteria would be:

#1 Keep ONE most recent .vbk file
#2 Keep ALL .vib files that have the same modified date or newer than #1
#3 Delete ALL remaining older .vib and .vbk files. NOTE: So there should ALWAYS be one most recent .vbk file left in the folder, and ALL same date or newer .vib files (if any). That way if script is run more than once it won't delete the ONE most recent .vib file and any same/newer .vib files (if any).

Comment: Strictly, it's a new question - otherwise we get the ever-moving goalposts. To convert text to code, highlight the text and press the `{}` symbol in the top bar of the edit window.

Comment: Thank you once again @Magoo for the revision! You're so good at this.